# Initialization of const array of struct

Tags: c#

How do I do a constant initialization an array of a structure type?  For example, in C I would do something like this:

```
struct Item {
    int a;
    char const * b;
};
Item items[] = {
    { 12, "Hello" },
    { 13, "Bye" },
};
```

I've been looking at various C# references but can't find an equivalent syntax. Is there one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sample code:

```
struct Item
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
};
Item[] items = {
    new Item { a = 12, b = "Hello" },
    new Item { a = 13, b = "Bye" }
};
```

Additional option to introduce parametrized constructor:

```
struct Item
{
    public int a;
    public string b;

    public Item(int a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
};
Item[] items = {
    new Item( 12, "Hello" ),
    new Item( 13, "Bye" )
};
```

As @YoYo suggested, removed `new[]` part.

**Tricky way** (for the case where `new Item` bothers you much)

Declare new class:

```
class Items : List<Item>
{
    public void Add(int a, string b)
    {
        Add(new Item(a, b));
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize it as:

```
Items items = new Items {
    { 12, "Hello" },
    { 13, "Bye" }
};
```

You can also apply `.ToArray` method of `List` to get an array of `Item`s.

```
Item[] items = new Items {
    { 12, "Hello" },
    { 13, "Bye" }
}.ToArray();
```

The trick is based on collection initializers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the **Add** method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

Comment: There is no short form that doesn't require me repeating the symbols?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Only via parametrized constructor. But still you have to repeat `new Item`.

Comment: Initialization of array code can be reduced more like:

`Item[] items = { new Item { a = 12, b = "Hello" }, new Item { a = 13, b = "Bye" } };`

Comment: The `new[]` part doesn't bother me, it's the repeated `new Item` part for every item. I guess this is closet I get though.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I added the sample without repeating `new Item`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do such concise initialization is using implicit conversion operator with a tuple:

```
struct Item
{
    public int a;
    public string b;

    public Item(int a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public static implicit operator Item(ValueTuple<int, string> tuple)
    {
        return new Item(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
};
```

Then the initialization can look as simple as this:

```
Item[] items =
{
    (12, "Hello"),
    (13, "Bye")
};
```

Please, note the parentheses `()` instead of curly brackets `{}`.

This solution doesn't require another class to be defined and doesn't use intermediate `List`.

Comment: Nice. Having tinkered with it I've noticed there's no need to use generics. I wanted to name the fields but generic tuples wouldn't take names. This worked for me: `public static implicit operator Item((int a, string b) tuple) { return new Item(tuple.a, tuple.b); }`

Answer (score -1):

[Triant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77255241/1271778) is the best in my opinion as it achieves the shortest style with the least amount of code whilst still sticking to `struct` (not using an intermediate `List` to achieve the goal which is to have an array). My comment to that answer makes it a tiny bit better in my opinion as it avoids using generics for the tuple and also (as a result), the tuple fields can now be named.

But that answer has given me an idea. What lead me to looking for a very brief style of initializing a struct array is needing to store an array of grouped data in the lightest possible way. So I thought why not use an array of tuples?

```
(int a, string b)[] items =
{
    (1, "string1"),
    (2, "string2"),
};
```

This achieves my initial goal, but I admit it's not answering the op's question.