# Elegant initialization of an array of class instances in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class Fraction
{
   int numerator;
   int denominator;

   public Fraction(int n, int d)
   {
      // set the member variables
   }

   // And then a bunch of other methods
}
```

I want to initialize an array of them in a nice way, and this post is a big list of approaches that are error prone or syntactically cumbersome.

Of course an array constructor would be nice, but there's no such thing:

```
public Fraction[](params int[] numbers)
```

So I'm forced to use a method like

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(params int[] numbers)
{
    // Make an array and pull pairs of numbers for constructor calls
}
```

which is relatively clunky, but I don't see a way around it.

Both forms are error prone because a user could mistakenly pass an odd number of parameters, maybe because s/he skipped a value, which would leave the function scratching its head wondering what the user actually wanted. It could throw an exception, but then the user would need to try/catch. I'd rather not impose that on the user if possible. So let's enforce pairs.

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(params int[2][] pairs)
```

But you can't call this CreateArray in a nice way, like

```
Fraction.CreateArray({0,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,7}, {1,42});
```

You can't even do

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(int[2][] pairs)
// Then later...
int[2][] = {{0,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,7}, {1,42}};
Fraction.CreateArray(numDenArray);
```

Note that this would work just fine in C++ (I'm pretty sure).

You're forced to do one of the following instead, which is abhorrent. The syntax is terrible and it seems really awkward to use a jagged array when all the elements have the same length.

```
int[2][] fracArray = {new int[2]{0,1}, /*etc*/);
Fraction.CreateArray(fracArray);
// OR
Fraction.CreateArray(new int[2]{0,1}, /*etc*/);
```

Similarly, Python-style tuples are illegal and the C# version is icky:

```
Fraction.CreateArray(new Tuple<int,int>(0,1), /*etc*/);
```

The use of a pure 2D array might take the following form, but it's illegal, and I'm sure there's no legal way to express it:

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(int[2,] twoByXArray)
// Then later...
Fraction[] fracArray = 
    Fraction.CreateArray(new int[2,4]{{0,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,6}});
```

This doesn't enforce pairs:

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(int[,] twoByXArray)
```

OK, how about

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray(int[] numerators, int[] denominators)
```

But then the two arrays might have different lengths. C++ allows

```
public static Fraction[] CreateArray<int N>(int[N] numerators, int[N] denominators)
```

but, well, this isn't C++, is it?

This sort of thing is illegal:

```
public static implicit operator Fraction[](params int[2][] pairs)
```

and unworkable anyway, again because of the abhorrent syntax:

```
Fraction[] fracArray = new Fraction[](new int[2]{0,1}, /*etc*/ );
```

This might be nice:

```
public static implicit operator Fraction(string s)
{
    // Parse the string into numerator and denominator with
    // delimiter '/'
}
```

Then you can do

```
string[] fracStrings = new string[] {"0/1", /*etc*/};
Fraction[] fracArray = new Fraction[fracStrings.Length];
int index = 0;
foreach (string fracString in fracStrings) {
    fracArray[index] = fracStrings[index];
}
```

I don't like this approach for five reasons. One, the implicit cast unavoidably instantiates a new object, but we already have a perfectly good one, namely the one we're trying to initialize. Two, it can be confusing to read. Three, it forces you to do explicitly what I wanted to encapsulate in the first place. Four, it leaves room for bad formatting. Five, it involves one-time parsing of string literals, which is more like a practical joke than good programming style.

The following also requires wasteful instantiation:

```
var fracArray = Array.ConvertAll(numDenArray, item => (Fraction)item);
```

The following use of a property has the same problem unless you use those terrible jagged arrays:

```
public int[2] pair {
    set {
        numerator = value[0];
        denominator = value[1];
    }
}
// Then later...
var fracStrings = new int[2,4] {{0,1}, /*etc*/};
var fracArray = new Fraction[fracStrings.Length];
int index = 0;
foreach (int[2,] fracString in fracStrings) {
    fracArray[index].pair = fracStrings[index];
}
```

This variation doesn't enforce pairs:

```
foreach (int[,] fracString in fracStrings) {
    fracArray[index].pair = fracStrings[index];
}
```

Again, this approach is big anyway.

These are all of the ideas I know how to derive. Is there a good solution?

Comment: There is a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534114/initialization-of-const-array-of-struct) which proposes a trick using a list of objects.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I can't think of an elegant, and at the same time memory efficient solution for array.

But there is an elegant solution for list (and similar) utilizing the C# 6 [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) feature:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Add(this ICollection<Fraction> target, int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        target.Add(new Fraction(numerator, denominator));
    }
}
```

With that extension method in place, you can easily initialize a `Fraction` list for instance:

```
var list = new List<Fraction> { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 7 }, { 1, 42 } };
```

And of course, although not memory efficient, you can use it to initialize `Fraction` array either:

```
var array = new List<Fraction> { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 7 }, { 1, 42 } }.ToArray();
```

or even making it more concise by declaring a list derived class with implicit array conversion operator:

```
public class FractionList : List<Fraction>
{
    public static implicit operator Fraction[](FractionList x) => x?.ToArray();
}
```

and then use

```
Fraction[] array = new FractionList { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 7 }, { 1, 42 } };
```

Comment: I like this for `List<>`!

Comment: Great solution! And memory-efficiency should be of no concern, if we are talking about hand written tuples in code! If there are more than 1000 they should be in a resource file!

Comment: Does this require a certain version of C#? I tried the `new List<Fraction> { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, [...]` example but it says Add doesn't take 2 arguments, although the extension is in scope. (Note: I'm not the asker)

Comment: @GeorgeT: `Add` as an extension method like that requires C# 6. If you're stuck with an ancient version, you can always make an actual class that has `Add` as a normal method. That way you wouldn't have to use `List<T>` either which might have superfluous features for you, you could just make your own class which just implements `IEnumerable` and has an `Add` method which are the requirements for using the collection initializer syntax.

Comment: .NET Fiddle for @MattiVirkkunen's "ancient" approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SXlNKz

Answer (score 8):

You could create a fraction array builder with a fluent interface. It would lead to something like

```
public class FractionArrayBuilder
{
  private readonly List<Fraction> _fractions = new List<Fraction>();

  public FractionArrayBuilder Add(int n, int d)
  {
    _fractions.Add(new Fraction(n, d));
    return this;
  }

  public Fraction[] Build()
  {
    return _fractions.ToArray();
  }
}
```

which can be called using

```
var fractionArray = new FractionArrayBuilder()
  .Add(1,2)
  .Add(3,4)
  .Add(3,1)
  .Build();
```

which is an easy to understand statement.

I have made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bqrzqT) to demonstrate.

Comment: you could drop the first arg to the `Add` method and simply return `this`

Comment: This won't compile: if `Add()` is supposed to be an extension method, it needs to be `static`. But I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be just an instance method.

Comment: you are both correct. I've edited.

Answer (score 7):

The most succinct way I can think of for your particular example involves writing an implicit operator for the Fraction class:

```
public sealed class Fraction
{
    public Fraction(int n, int d)
    {
        Numerator   = n;
        Deniminator = d;
    }

    public int Numerator   { get; }
    public int Deniminator { get; }

    public static implicit operator Fraction(int[] data)
    {
        return new Fraction(data[0], data[1]);
    }
}
```

Then you can initialise it like this:

```
var fractions = new Fraction[]
{
    new [] {1, 2},
    new [] {3, 4},
    new [] {5, 6}
};
```

Unfortunately you still need the `new []` on each line, so I don't think this gains very much over the normal array initialisation syntax:

```
var fractions = new []
{
    new Fraction(1, 2),
    new Fraction(3, 4),
    new Fraction(5, 6)
};
```

I suppose you could write a "local" `Func<>` with a short name to simplify the initialisation somewhat:

```
Func<int, int, Fraction> f = (x, y) => new Fraction(x, y);

var fractions = new []
{
    f(1, 2),
    f(3, 4),
    f(5, 6)
};
```

The drawback is that you'd need to add that extra line (initialising a `Func<>`) wherever you wanted to initialise the array - or have a private static method in the class instead - but then that method would be in scope throughout the class, which isn't ideal if it has a single-letter name.

However, the advantage of this approach is that it is very flexible.

I toyed with the idea of calling the inline function `_`, but I'm really not sure about that...

```
Func<int, int, Fraction> _ = (x, y) => new Fraction(x, y);

var fractions = new []
{
    _(1, 2),
    _(3, 4),
    _(5, 6)
};
```

Comment: Yeah, the syntax is better but still clunky. Besides, I would say it's error prone because the data parameter might not have two elements. In the worst case, it has only 0 or 1, which will throw an exception, and potential exceptions make a technique harder to implement.

Comment: Instead of a local `Func`, I would consider making it a `public static` method on some class, which you can access by `using static`.

Comment: Great observations, I appreciate the all of your insight and explanations, I found the _ "underscore" comical.